# Expiring Kubelet Certificate on port 10250

Tags: kubernetes, certificate, kubelet

i have an issue with an expiring cert on one of our kubernetes nodes.
Checking the cert which is used on port 10250, the result is telling me the cert will expire on July 23:

[image]

I have checked the certificate which is used by kubelet service which shows me this information:

[image]

I double-checked all certs, I am aware of located at /etc/kuberbetes/pki as well as at /var/lib/kubelet/pki. All certs on that locations are valid and do not expire.

Is there another location with certs that I am missing here?

Answer (score 1):

The `kubelet-client-current.pem` you're looking at is the client certificate that Kubelet would use, authenticating with the Kubernetes API.

The server certificate you're looking for should be the `/var/lib/kubelet/kubelet.crt` one.

```
# openssl x509 -text -noout -in /var/lib/kubelet/pki/kubelet-client-current.pem  | grep -A4 'X509v3 extensions'
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Key Usage: critical
                Digital Signature, Key Encipherment
            X509v3 Extended Key Usage: 
                TLS Web Client Authentication

# openssl x509 -text -noout -in /var/lib/kubelet/pki/kubelet.crt  | grep -A4 'X509v3 extensions'
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Key Usage: critical
                Digital Signature, Key Encipherment
            X509v3 Extended Key Usage: 
                TLS Web Server Authentication
```

The first one serves to authenticate a client, the later a server.

Answer (score 0):

Also, check to see if your kublet is being started with the --rotate-certificates=true and the --rotate-server-certificates=true flags.

I checked this on the nodes in my cluster, and they were not set, and the kubelets on my nodes were still using one of the older certificates, rather than the one that kubeadm created when the certificates were last renewed.

My nodes were running on Ubuntu, and services were maintained by systemd, so at the path /etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d there were files there that I edit as shown below to add these rotation flags:

```
root@UNI-DEV-2-KubW-1:/etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d# ls
10-kubeadm.conf  20-extra-args.conf
root@UNI-DEV-2-KubW-1:/etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d# cat 20-extra-args.conf 
[Service]
Environment="KUBELET_EXTRA_ARGS=--fail-swap-on=false"
root@UNI-DEV-2-KubW-1:/etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d# cat 10-kubeadm.conf 
# Note: This dropin only works with kubeadm and kubelet v1.11+
[Service]
Environment="KUBELET_KUBECONFIG_ARGS=--bootstrap-kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/bootstrap-kubelet.conf --kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf"
Environment="KUBELET_CONFIG_ARGS=--config=/var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml"
# This is a file that "kubeadm init" and "kubeadm join" generates at runtime, populating the KUBELET_KUBEADM_ARGS variable dynamically
EnvironmentFile=-/var/lib/kubelet/kubeadm-flags.env
# This is a file that the user can use for overrides of the kubelet args as a last resort. Preferably, the user should use
# the .NodeRegistration.KubeletExtraArgs object in the configuration files instead. KUBELET_EXTRA_ARGS should be sourced from this file.
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/default/kubelet
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/bin/kubelet $KUBELET_KUBECONFIG_ARGS $KUBELET_CONFIG_ARGS $KUBELET_KUBEADM_ARGS $KUBELET_EXTRA_ARGS --rotate-certificates=true --rotate-server-certificates=true
root@UNI-DEV-2-KubW-1:/etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d#
```

I was probably suppose to add these to the 20-extra-args.conf, but added them as shown, and it worked.

After editing these files, I entered the following commands:

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl restart kubelet
```

After this it turned out to be necessary to approve the creation of new kubelet certificates as in the following:

```
kubectl get csr
kubectl certificate approve <csrname>
```

After approving the csrs that appeared, the kubelet began using the new certificates on port 10250.

I got this information from the stack exchange post by aitorhh at the following address:

https://serverfault.com/questions/1068751/var-lib-kubelet-pki-kubelet-crt-is-expired-how-to-renew-it